# Converting general equation to parametric and vector.

Tags: vector-spaces

If the equation of my plane is  $(x−1,y−5,z−6)\cdot\vec{N}=0$.
What can I do to convert it to parametric equation and vector equation?

Comment: [Similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194582/how-to-find-the-vector-equation-of-a-plane-given-the-scalar-equation/1194593#1194593).  P.S. I actually like Ivo's answer better than mine.

Comment: i thought the general formula was like this: Ax + By + Cz + D = 0, if N⃗ =(-8,-14,16)

Answer (score 0):

If for example the general equation of the plane is: $3x + 4y - z = 5$, then let:

$x = s, y = t$, then solve for $z = 3s + 4t-5 \to (x,y,z) = (s,t,3s+4t-5) = s(1,0,3) + t(0,1,4) + (0,0,-5)$ is the parametric equation.

Comment: But my general equation is (x-1,y-5,z-6)⋅N⃗ =0 
N⃗  = (-8,-14,16)
How do I convert it to the normal general equation

Comment: What I don't understand is that in your example you have 3x+4y−z=5, that is easy to follow, but how can I simplify this: (x−1,y−5,z−6)⋅(-8,-14,16)= 0

Comment: @Julio How do you do a dot product?

Comment: (-8x+8)+(-14y+70)+(16z-96)= 0 Then, -8x -14y +16z = 18?

Comment: @Julio That's correct.  So as you can see $-8x-14y+16z=18$ is exactly the same equation as $(x-1,y-5,z-6)\cdot(-8,-14,16)=0$.

Comment: Also, if you want to comment a specific person you should add @[username] so that they get messaged.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
\eqalign{
  & 0 = \left( {x - 1,y - 5,z - 6} \right) \cdot \mathop N\limits^ \to  \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 0 = \left( {x,y,z} \right) \cdot \mathop N\limits^ \to   - \left( {1,5,6} \right) \cdot \mathop N\limits^ \to  \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {x,y,z} \right) \cdot \mathop N\limits^ \to   = \left( {1,5,6} \right) \cdot \mathop N\limits^ \to  \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad N_x \,x + N_y \,y + N_z \,z = N_x  + 5N_y \, + 6N_z  \cr} 
$$
and that's the "standard" equation of the plane $ax+by+cz=d$.

For 
$$
\mathop N\limits^ \to   = \left( {\matrix{
   { - 8}  \cr 
   { - 14}  \cr 
   {16}  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
you get
$$
\eqalign{
  &  \Rightarrow \quad  - 8\,x - 14\,y + 16\,z =  - 8 - 70\, + 96 = 18  \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad  - 4\,x - 7\,y + 8\,z = 9 \cr} 
$$

For the parametric equation, you have two approaches: I don't know which one you are considering.

The *linear system* approach is to consider that the "standard" equation is one linear
equation in $3$ unknowns.
Its solution will depend on two "free" parameters.
In this case you can choose for instance to put
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  x = t \hfill \cr 
  y = s \hfill \cr 
  z = {{9 + 4t + 7s} \over 8} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
Aside, be advised that when you have more that two equations (line) then
you shall take care of the rank of the coefficient- and total- matrix.

The *vectorial* approach consists in that we can choose two independent vectors $\bf u , \bf v$ normal to $\vec{N}$
and put
$$
{\bf x} = \lambda \,{\bf u} + \mu \,{\bf v}
$$
For instance
$$
{\bf u} = \left( {\matrix{
   7  \cr 
   { - 4}  \cr 
   0  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad {\bf v} = \left( {\matrix{
   2  \cr 
   0  \cr 
   1  \cr 
 } } \right)\quad \left\{ \matrix{
  x = 7\lambda  + 2\mu  \hfill \cr 
  y =  - 4\lambda  \hfill \cr 
  z = \mu  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$